# How to Curve a specific part of a Mesh (Pan)

Tags: mesh, shrinkwrap, proportional-editing, surface-deform

Hello im new to blender and gave myself the task to model a simple frying pan.

I am almost finished but still need to connect the handle to the round pan,
addet an image of the meshes.
How can I curve the metallic part only in the front but not in the back ?
Surface Deform didnt worked for me since it shrinks down my mesh to an plane.
[image]

Comment: Suggestion. Please consider  [proportional edit] on the metal handle.  Please show some of your initial attempts or finished work with [proportional edit]. A [shrink wrap] modifier might be added after the above step

Comment: Of course there are plenty of videos discussing proportional edit on the  famous video website that has a name that rhymes with noonoob

Answer (score 1):

[proportional edit] did not work for me, it was my first time using it and even with mirror modefier it felt more like sculpting .

1. I deleted the mesh to the point it became almost like a plane with many subdivides .
2. Used the shrinkwrap modefier und extruded it again to make it look like before.
   [image]

[image]